# Showing an editable textbox in my GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I'm displaying a Gridview which shows a list of questions with a checkbox for pass or fail. What I would like to do is when they tick the checkbox for a fail a textbox appears in the next column to give the reason why. The code for my Gridview is as follows

```
    <asp:GridView ID="QuestionsGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        BorderStyle="None" class="gridView"  
                  GridLines="None" ShowFooter="True" TotalRows="0" 
                  Width="950px" CellPadding="5" CssClass="gridView"  
                  EmptyDataText="No rows found." 
                  style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" 
                  OnRowDataBound="QuestionsGrid_RowDataBound" IgnoreFlagIdpsc="" 
                  OnRowEditing="QuestionsGrid_RowEditing"   onRowCommand="QuestionsGrid_RowCommand" > 
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
                  <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="200px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
                  <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="500px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>                
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Passed" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked="true" ></asp:CheckBox>
                 </ItemTemplate>                   
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="100px" Font-Size="10pt"></asp:TextBox>
                 </ItemTemplate>                   
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I have tried setting an event onCheckChanged with my CheckBox which doesn't work. I would like to do this without using editable buttons for my GridView.

Comment: what you done on onCheckChanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next code should work:

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var checkbox = sender as CheckBox;

    //version 1: show the text box on click
    checkbox.Parent.FindControl("TextBox1").Visible = true;

    //version 1: show the text box based on checkbox state
    checkbox.Parent.FindControl("TextBox1").Visible = checkbox.Checked;
}
```

Don't forget to add the handler (and the autopostback) from aspx markup with

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Passed">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:CheckBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```